# Is it possible to reassign req.params in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'll start with some context:
I have a RESTful API Server that includes routes for managing users; e.g.

`PUT .../users/:id/profile`

As part of our authentication flow we verify the user's identity and compare the id in the url with the id retrieved from our IDP.

What I'm trying to do is implement a 'me' replacement approach; where a user, instead of providing their id in the url, can simply provide 'me' instead, and the id is reassigned with id retrieved from the IDP based on their authentication. I've seen Google do this for some of their APIs. E.g.
`.../users/me/profile`

So far I've been attempting a simple replacement with the assumption that a modified req.params will propagate forward:

```
req.params.id = req.params.id === 'me'
  ? session.id
  : req.params.id
```

This wasn't working so I did a bit of reading up on it and apparently req.params gets built with each middleware function (when .use() is called), so reassigning req.params.id doesn't propagate throughout the app as I had hoped.

Currently all our business logic pulls the id from req.params so I was wondering if there's a way to get the above behaviour to work to avoid refactoring all my business logic?

I understand that req.params is built from parsing the url; so would modifying the url be an option?; to replace 'me' with the id; so that req.params is populated as intended? If so, how could this be achieved?

Or, if you have a nicer alternative to getting the above 'me' replacement behaviour to work then I'm all ears!

Comment: ...if user's id is not provided in the URL it should be provided somwhere else. Otherwise how your RESTful application could know user's id?

Comment: Yes, we can retrieve the id from the authentication flow; however the issue is all my logic inspects req.params.id for the id. What I'm trying to do it inject the id I receive from the authentication flow into req.params.id.

Comment: Got it... Then your attempt to assign `req.params.id` should work. Just tested it and everything looks fine i.e. you can assign `req.params.id` anything you want. Have you tried creating new route for /users/me/profile?

Comment: Tested again locally; the modified req.params.id remains in place for the duration of the current middleware function. Once the next middleware function in the chain is called, req.params is reset.

Comment: Then you need to pass it from one function in the chain to another using next()... something like this `router.get('/', function(req,res,next) {next (null, {some:data});
}, foo);

function foo(req,res,next,data){ }`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Global middleware (that you add using `app.use()` or `router.use()`) is typically not even aware of any route handlers that declare parameters, so `req.params` usually isn't even populated.</s>

A solution would be to "inline" the modifying middleware:

```
app.put('/users/:id/profile', middleware, ...)
```

But that would require rewriting all your route handlers.

As you already point out correctly, you *can* modify the URL:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url === '/users/me/profile') {
    req.url = '/users/1234/profile';
  }
  next();
});

app.put('/users/:id/profile', ...)
```

Instead of having to match each URL specifically, you can perform substring matches, or use a list of all URL's that may contain an `:id` parameter (and therefore, may contain the `me` identifier).

I just realized that this should work (using [`req.param()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.param)):

```
router.param('id', function(req, res, next, id) {
  if (id === 'me') {
    req.params.id = '1234';
  }
  next();
});
```

This should be added to routers that declare parameters, either in route handlers directly, or in mountpoints.

A convoluted example:

```
let childRouter = express.Router({ mergeParams : true });

childRouter.put('/profile', ...);

let parentRouter = express.Router({ mergeParams : true });

parentRouter.use('/:id', childRouter);

parentRouter.param('id', function(req, res, next, id) {
  if (id === 'me') {
    req.params.id = '1234';
  }
  next();
});

app.use('/users', parentRouter);
```

Because `parentRouter` declares a mountpoint `/:id`, it should get the resolving function.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified more; yes, am using route handlers like you've mentioned. However, I have routers routing to routers. I have a router for /users/:id, which routers to another router that looks for /profile etc. So req.url at that point only shows /profile. I tried modifying originalUrl, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Mitch see my edit, there's an alternative way of rewriting that may be more robust.

Comment: Did some testing today and the req.param() approach works like a charm. Thank you very much! Not sure I fully understand why setting req.params.id within req.param() works, but not within other middleware though.

Comment: @Mitch I think that `req.param()` is called during the processing of `req.params` for a route, whereas regular middleware is called before the request hits the route handler.